# How do I include the base folder in the list of sub-folders using get-childitem?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I would like to include the base folder in the list of sub-directories.

If I use Get-ChildItem and search for folders:

```
$startFolder = "C:\Scripts"
Get-ChildItem $startfolder -recurse |
Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | 
Select FullName
```

I get a list of the sub-folders like this:

```
C:\Scripts\folder1
C:\Scripts\folder2
C:\Scripts\folder2\folderA
```

I would like to see:

```
C:\Scripts             <-- include the starting folder
C:\Scripts\folder1
C:\Scripts\folder2
C:\Scripts\folder2\folderA
```

I saw an example on technet like this:

```
$startFolder = "C:\Scripts"
$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
"$startFolder -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"

$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder -recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | Sort-Object)
foreach ($i in $colItems)
    {
        $subFolderItems = (Get-ChildItem $i.FullName | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
        $i.FullName + " -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($subFolderItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"
    }
```

They break it into two pieces.  Process the starting folder, then process the sub-folders.   Is that the only way or can the starting folder be included in one command?

It seems like such a simple thing...

Comment: possible duplicate of [can I include root folder to get-childitem output programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742816/can-i-include-root-folder-to-get-childitem-output-programmatically). Although I like this answer better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution:

```
$startFolder = "C:\Scripts"
$(Get-Item $startFolder
Get-ChildItem $startfolder -recurse |
Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}) | 
Select FullName
```

Add a `Get-Item` for your $startFolder, and wrap that along with your `Get-ChildItem` in a `sub-expression` so it's all in the same collection.

Comment: This solution is typically the accepted one for this scenario.

Comment: Thanks.  Too bad it doesn't include a parameter for that

Comment: @kevro The response to that comment is in the name of the cmdlet `Get-ChildItem` is to get the children and not the host. More often than not that is what people are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the behavior, change it. If you use these two lines, you can get the skeleton for a proxy function:

```
$MetaData = New-Object System.Management.Automation.CommandMetaData (Get-Command Get-ChildItem)
[System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create($MetaData)
```

Then you can add this code in the process block:

```
$GetItemParams = @{
    Force = $Force
}
switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
    Items { $GetItemParams.Path = $Path }
    LiteralItems { $GetItemParams.LiteralPath = $LiteralPath }

    default {
        Write-Error "Unable to call Get-Item on base: Unknown ParameterSetName"
    }
}
Get-Item @GetItemParams
```

After doing that, your final proxy function would look like this:

```
function Get-ChildItem {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Items', SupportsTransactions=$true, HelpUri='http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308')]
    param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Items', Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string[]]
        ${Path},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='LiteralItems', Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [Alias('PSPath')]
        [string[]]
        ${LiteralPath},

        [Parameter(Position=1)]
        [string]
        ${Filter},

        [string[]]
        ${Include},

        [string[]]
        ${Exclude},

        [Alias('s')]
        [switch]
        ${Recurse},

        [switch]
        ${Force},

        [switch]
        ${Name})

    begin
    {
        try {
            $outBuffer = $null
            if ($PSBoundParameters.TryGetValue('OutBuffer', [ref]$outBuffer))
            {
                $PSBoundParameters['OutBuffer'] = 1
            }
            $wrappedCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Get-ChildItem', [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet)
            $scriptCmd = {& $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters }
            $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline($myInvocation.CommandOrigin)
            $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
        } catch {
            throw
        }
    }

    process
    {
        # Modification starts here
        $GetItemParams = @{
            Force = $Force
        }
        switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
            Items { $GetItemParams.Path = $Path }
            LiteralItems { $GetItemParams.LiteralPath = $LiteralPath }

            default {
                Write-Error "Unable to call Get-Item on base: Unknown ParameterSetName"
            }
        }
        Get-Item @GetItemParams
        # Modification ends here

        try {
            $steppablePipeline.Process($_)
        } catch {
            throw
        }
    }

    end
    {
        try {
            $steppablePipeline.End()
        } catch {
            throw
        }
    }
    <#

    .ForwardHelpTargetName Get-ChildItem
    .ForwardHelpCategory Cmdlet

    #>

}
```

Of course, you could name the function anything you want if you don't want your function to get called every time you're trying to use Get-ChildItem.

Answer (score 0):

I like the File System Security PowerShell Module 3.2.3 (NTFSSecurity) which permits long foldernames and includes the -Directory flag, so my solution works as:

```
((Get-Item2 -Path $startFolder -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue),
 (Get-ChildItem2 -Path $startFolder -Recurse -Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)).FullName |
     ForEach-Object {
          process-folder $_ ...
     }
```