# Set-ACL with folder exclude

Tags: powershell, permissions, acl

I'm trying to set modify permissions for a folder, sub-folders and files and exclude a specific folder inside.
I tried two methods but on each of them I have a small problem.
On the first one, I apply all permissions successfully but the "temp" folder exclude is not working. it gets the permissions as well:

```
$Acl = Get-Acl "C:\Users\John\Desktop\test"
$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", "Modify", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
Set-Acl "C:\Users\John\Desktop\test" $Acl -Exclude "C:\Users\John\Desktop\test\temp"
```

The second option is excluding the folder, but permissions are not set for the root folder as well.
I know that his is because of the get-childitem, but I couldn't understand how to include the root folder as well in the code:

```
$Acl = Get-Acl "C:\Users\John\Desktop\test"
$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", "Modify", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
get-childitem "C:\Users\John\Desktop\test\" -Recurse -Exclude "C:\Users\John\Desktop\test\temp" | Set-Acl -AclObject $Acl
```

I'll appreciate for your help.
Thank you!

Comment: For first one, try `-Exclude temp`.

Comment: For 2nd one: `$dir = "C:\Users\John\Desktop\test\"; $(get-item $dir; get-childitem $dir -recurse -Exclude "C:\Users\John\Desktop\test\temp") | Set-Acl -AclObject $Acl`. From https://stackoverflow.com/a/29157250/7571258

Comment: Thinking about it, in 1st case the `-Exclude` cannot work because you pass `ContainerInherit`. So "temp" sub dir will inherit ACL anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much zett42! unfortunately for the second option - the folder still not excluded :(

Comment: You have to set a different access rule for the root folder, to prevent inheritance: `New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", "Modify", "ObjectInherit", "NoPropagateInherit", "Allow")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I did it right. at this moment I ran the code at home so I'll test it more deeper tomorrow at work.
This is what I did:

```
$Acl = Get-Acl "C:\Users\John\Desktop\Test"
$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", "Modify", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
get-childitem "C:\Users\John\Desktop\Test\" -Recurse -Exclude "TempFolder" | Set-Acl -AclObject $Acl

##########################################################

$AclRoot = Get-Acl "C:\Users\John\Desktop\Test"
$ArRoot = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", "Modify", "ObjectInherit", "NoPropagateInherit", "Allow")
$AclRoot.SetAccessRule($ArRoot)
Get-Item "C:\Users\John\Desktop\Test" | Set-Acl -AclObject $AclRoot
```

The results are:

- All sub-folders and files with "Everyone - Modify", except TempFolder.
- "Test" root folder with "Everyone - Modify" - "This folder and files" (special permissions)
  I hope it will do the job for my needs at work.

Thanks again!